# Change to black and white (without greys) in AE

Tags: after-effects, premiere

I am trying to convert an After Effect layer of regular color video to a completely Black & White layer, that is, Black remains black, but anything not black will turn into snow white. Is there an simple way to accomplish this in After Effects or Premiere? I have struggled to find an easy way and applied different Effects (Channel Combiner, Hue/Sat), with some success, but it doesn't seem to fully convert the layer to a complete black and white image. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The effect that does what you specifically want is called [threshold](https://helpx.adobe.com/after-effects/using/stylize-effects.html#threshold_effect).

Comment: That has done it, thanks! It was difficult to Google the answer across tutorials as when I type bw effects it always refers to greyscale.